# Spring Boot Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis broker connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I have a very simple Spring Boot 2.7.6 ActiveMQ Artemis app which listens for messages.

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
      DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
      // This provides all auto-configured defaults to this factory, including the message converter
      configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
      // You could still override some settings if necessary.
      return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-queue-1")
    public void listen(String in) {
       System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

Here's the code that configures the embedded broker. I was just guessing by adding multiple acceptors. Different posts refer to `addConnectorConfiguration`, but none of them seem to work so far.

```java
package hello;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.TransportConfiguration;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class ArtemisConfig implements ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration) {
      configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration("remote", "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");
    }
}
```

With this simple `application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.mode=embedded
spring.artemis.embedded.server-id=54321
spring.artemis.embedded.queues=my-queue-1
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true
```

Then I have another Spring Boot app which produces messages and sends them to the broker address.

```java
package broker.producer;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class JmsProducer {

  @Value("${spring.jms.template.default-destination}")
  private String defaultDestination;

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsProducer.class);

  @Bean
  public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

      return activeMQConnectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver() {
    return new JndiDestinationResolver();
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory());
    template.setPubSubDomain(false); // false for a Queue, true for a Topic
    template.setDefaultDestinationName(defaultDestination);

    return template;
  }


  public void send(String message) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate();

    log.info("Sending message='{}'", message);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
    log.info("Sent message='{}'", message);
  }
}
```

Then I start each of the apps and try calling send method and I am unable to connect to the broker from the producer app due to this error:

```
2024-01-16 10:25:00.596 ERROR 30486 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]] with root cause
```

The producer app is able to connect to a Docker instance of ActiveMQ Artemis just fine.

For now both apps are running on the same machine, but in prod I'm hoping to have each app running in a separate pod.

Comment: 1. For now both apps are running on the same machine, but in prod hoping to have each app running in a separate pod.
2. I was just guessing by adding multiple connectors, different posts refer to addConnectorConfiguration, but none of them seem to work so far.
3. I have removed `spring.artemis.broker-url`, but no difference so far. 
4. Thx for your help

Comment: I have tried all the above and no difference, I am still getting: `message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]] with root cause`

Comment: Do you see _any_ evidence that the embedded broker is started (e.g. a log message like `AMQ221007: Server is now live`)? I see this when I run Spring app like your consumer.

Comment: BTW, why are you using such an old version of Spring?

Comment: 1. I see: `o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://localhost Started` but noting about broker.
2. I am using old Spring b/c my team does not have the time to upgrade. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a very simple project as a proof-of-concept to ensure what you were doing was possible and everything worked fine for me. The embedded broker was started and accepted connections from remote clients on port `61616`.

Here's `Application.java`:

```java
package hello;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all auto-configured defaults to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some settings if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-queue-1")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }
}
```

Here's `ArtemisConfig.java`:

```java
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class ArtemisConfig implements ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration) {
       try {
          configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration("remote", "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Here's my `application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.mode=embedded
spring.artemis.embedded.server-id=54321
spring.artemis.embedded.queues=my-queue-1
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true
```

Finally, here's my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
      <relativePath/>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-customized-activemq-artemis</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
      <spring.version>2.7.6</spring.version>
      <activemq.artemis.version>2.19.1</activemq.artemis.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
     <version>${activemq.artemis.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

I start the application like so:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I see logging like this:

```
...
... AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 0.0.0.0:61616 for protocols [CORE]
... AMQ221007: Server is now live
...
```

I can send a message to the broker from another application and the `JmsListener` receives it.

I uploaded the [project to GitHub](https://github.com/jbertram/spring-boot-customized-activemq-artemis).

Comment: So I have found my issue, I was using: `org.apache.activemq:artemis-server:2.31.2` instead of `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:2.19.1` The project complied just fine except it would not work. Thanks for your help Justin, your are the best!!

Comment: Any idea how to add basic user/pass auth? Is `ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager` the way to go? Thx

Comment: From what I can tell Spring doesn't have sufficient hooks to configure the `SecurityManager` on the `EmbeddedActiveMQ` instance, and that's likely intentional. I believe embedding the broker in Spring is meant for local use-cases only which is why it doesn't allow remote connections by default. For more advanced use-cases you'll either need to manager your own embedded instance or use `native` mode with an external instance.